# triggers SQL error sql syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error

Hello I am trying to little by little make triggers work. But The following code gives me the error 
Error(10,1): PLS-00103: Påträffade symbolen "INSERT"
In other words its referring to my insert into registrations and says that the symbol insert can't be found. I really don't understand why this is possible. Help is much appreciated

```
create or replace TRIGGER TR_Put_To_Waits   
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Registrations
REFERENCING NEW AS newline
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
HasntPassedCourse INT;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO HasntPassedCourse
FROM PassedCourses P
WHERE P.code != :newline.code AND P.cid != :newline.cid;

dbms_output.Put_line(HasntPassedCourse);

END;

insert into REGISTRATIONS
(CID,CODE,STATUS)
values
('arne','tda401','registered');
rollback;
```

Comment: What front-end tool are you using?  You probably need a `/` on a new line after the `END` to tell the front-end that your PL/SQL block is complete (you may also want to highlight the `create trigger` DDL statement and execute it if you're using a GUI).  But different front-ends may have different logic for how you separate statements.  If `registrations` is a view rather than a table (which would be necessary if you want to define an `instead of` trigger), it wouldn't make a lot of sense to define a trigger that doesn't insert into the base table(s).

Comment: oracle sql developer

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an INSTEAD OF trigger on a table. Try BEFORE or AFTER.

Comment: and check, if the trigger is existing and valid before you execute the insert statement